# Ĉu ĝustas diri "veganaj homoj"?

Tags: adjectives

> *Mia frato estas vegano.*

Ĉi tie, *vegan-* signifas "*iu kiu ne manĝas produktojn de bestoj*".

> *Tiu supo estas vegana.*

Tamen ĉi tie, *vegan-* signifas "*farita sen produktoj de bestoj*".

Ŝajnas al mi ke la radiko havas malsaman signifon depende ĉu ĝi estas substantivo aŭ adjektivo. Sed kio pri la sekva frazo?

> *Mi konas multajn veganajn homojn.*

Ĉu ĝi estas ĝusta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La radiko *vegan/* estas substantiva, do ĝia baza signifo estas 'homo, kiu vivas sen uzi bestajn produktojn'. Kiam oni adjektivigas ĝin al *vegana*, la ĝenerala signifo estas 'rilata al aŭ karakterizata de vegano(j)', kaj tiu signifo povas plipreciziĝi laŭ la kunteksto:

- Oni povas diri *vegana manĝaĵo*. Ĉi tie la signifo de *vegana* plipreciziĝis al 'taŭga por vegano(j)'.
- Oni povas diri *vegana homo*. Ĉi tie la signifo de *vegana* plipreciziĝis al 'estanta vegano'

Ambaŭ uzoj estas ĝustaj kaj sekvas la ĝeneralajn regulojn de adjektivigo de substantiva radiko.

La situacio estas iom alia ĉe la vortoj derivitaj de la radiko *vegetar/*, kiu malsame ol *vegan/* estas adjektiva radiko. Fakte, en la ĝenerala lingvouzo la radiko *vegetar/* estas uzata en maniero iom stranga por Esperanta radiko: Kvankam oni kutime ne aldonas la sufikson *-an-* al adjektivaj radikoj, tamen estas uzata la formo *vegetarano*. La klarigo por tio estas, ke la uzado de la vortoj derivitaj de *vegetar/* imitas nacilingvajn formojn iom tro rekte, sen sufiĉe da konsidero al la interna logiko de Esperanto. Tamen nun la uzo estas jam tiom enradikiĝinta, ke ne plu eblas ŝanĝi ĝin. (Sed oni ja povas formi tute Esperantecajn formojn *senvianda*, *senviandismo* kaj *senviandisto*.)

La difino de *vegetara* en ReVo (simile kiel en PIV) estas "Konforma al la doktrino de senvianda nutrado". En la uz-ekzemploj en ReVo kaj PIV "vegetara" rilatas al *manĝaĵo* aŭ *dieto*, sed en la efektiva lingvouzo, ĝi ofte ankaŭ rilatas al homo (kaj la vortumo de la difino tion ankaŭ permesas, ĉar ja ankaŭ homo povas esti konforma al iu doktrino). Krome estas foje uzata ankaŭ *vegetarana*, ekzemple en la nomo de la organizaĵo Tutmonda Esperantista Vegetarana Asocio.

Answer (score 2):

Ŝajnas al mi ke la baza vorto estas “vegan-o”, kaj ke “vegan-a” signifas “rilata al tia dieto kian manĝas vegano. Kontraste, La vorto ”vegetar-ano“ estas kunmetaĵo de ”vegetara“ kaj ”-ano“.

Se ni povas supozi ke la uzo de la adjektivaj formoj estas simetriaj (sufiĉe sekura supozo), vi tute pravas ke la esprimoj ”vegana homo“ aŭ ”vegetara homo“ estas iom strangaj, ĉar tiuj adjektivoj kutime priskribas la manĝaĵon.

Comment: Mi ankaux komparis kun *vegetarano*, kaj konsciis ke oni dirus *vegetara mangxajxo* kaj *vegetarana homo*. Do, tiel ne estas konfuzo.

Comment: Pardonu mian ŝercemon… :-) Sed do la demando estas ĉu ”vegana” signifas malsame en la frazoj: *La kanibalo manĝis veganan pladon* – *La kanibalo manĝis veganan homon*

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro - Mi pardonpetas se mi ne diris klare. Mi intencis aserti ke ambaux esprimoj (vegetara homo, vegana homo) estas evitindaj, cxar ambaux adjektivoj priskribas mangxajxon aux dieton.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander En ordo, tion mi komprenis. Sed mi ne indikis tion en mia komento, pardonon.

Answer (score 2):

> Vegano - Homo kiu ne manĝas produktojn de besta deveno...
>
> Vegana - Konforma al doktrino ne manĝi produktojn de besta deveno: ĉu la **vegetara kaj vegana nutraĵoj** disponigas al la homo sufiĉe da proteinoj?
>
> http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/vegan.html#vegan.0o

Vegana homo:
[image]

Vegano - Homo, kiu estas vegana:
[image]